# PHP stops running script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wrote this script where you go to localhost/censor.php/query and it sees if it is taken. Here is the code:

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    else
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

    return $pageURL;
}

$test = curPageURL();
$test = str_replace('http://localhost/censor.php/',"",$test);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","creepers2","spider");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

$usname = null;
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM main WHERE urls='$test'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die(mysqli_error($con))) {
    $usname = $row['urls'];
    if ($usname=$test)
        echo "Taken!";
    else
        echo"YEAH!";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If you to localhost/censor.php/queryinthedatabase it prints out taken. However, if you go to localhost/censor.php/querynotinthedatabase, it prints nothing.
Help please?

Comment: First of all, I hope those aren't your real login credentials. Second of all, what does your apache error log say? Does it have a PHP exception logged? We could surely use that :-)

Comment: No, just some funny thing i like. I don't know what the apache error log is, what is it?

Comment: You need to be careful about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a simple query: `SELECT * FROM main WHERE urls='$test'`. That's fine (SQL injections aside).

Now, you're fetching all results and looping through them by using `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die(mysqli_error($con)))`. That said, if there were no results, it won't loop through any objects as it can't fetch any.

You should use something like `mysqli_num_rows`. For example:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM main WHERE urls='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($test) . "'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    echo "Taken!";
}
else {
    echo "YEAH!";
}
```

Now you're doing the same query (selecting all rows where `urls` is equal to `$test`), but instead of looping through the returned rows, you count the amount of rows that the query returned. If it equals `1`, it's taken.

Also, please escape any user-input you put into your queries; don't get to be yet another victim of SQL injections. **Never trust the user!**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `if ($usname=$test)` instead of `if ($usname==$test)`

Comment: You should have if ($usname==$test), it's not about trying this.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a variable value inside an if statment which is wrong, you should use double equl coparison operator to compare them, simply change

```
if ($usname==$test)
```

Also to debug your query you should move your mysqli_error to the query itself

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM main WHERE urls='$test'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Your code is highly vulnerable to mysql injections, learn more in this usefull post [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) you should use prepared statement to avoid any risk.